# VBA: Automating Loading of Data from Excel into PowerPoint Internal Chart Data

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am looking to script the automated loading of data from an Excel Worksheet directly into the embedded Chart Data Source within PowerPoint - as opposed to copying the chart in Excel and pasting the linked chart into PowerPoint.

I have attached a link to an image which demonstrates (I hope) my intention.

[image]

I tried to implement some of the code on :
www.think-cell.com/en/support/manual/exceldataautomation.shtml#x28-21500022.1

But not entirely sure if this is the right approach, plus I am having issues debugging the code for:

```
   Dim tcaddin As Object 
   Set tcaddin = _ 
    Application.COMAddIns("thinkcell.addin").Object
```

And genuinely confused as to where in my code to implement what it calls the signature:

```
tcaddin.UpdateChart( _ 
    pres As PowerPoint.Presentation, _ 
    strName As String, _ 
    rgData As Excel.Range, _ 
    bTransposed As Boolean _ 
)
```

Genuinely not sure if I've gone about this the wrong way or if it's even possible, but some new and exciting approaches would be massively appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add parts of an excel document to a powerpoint, you can paste the data so that it embeds and links to that document.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/insert-excel-data-in-powerpoint-0690708a-5ce6-41b4-923f-11d57554138d

Look at the above link and try the section Link a section of data in Excel to PowerPoint.

Then everytime you open the powerpoint it will ask if you want to update the links that are attached to the excel document.

Comment: Problem being that I'm not sure I'd be able to automate this transfer from Excel to PowerPoint.... is that possible? Also can I automate Chart creation from embedded data such as this?

Comment: You can run some code that will open the powerpoint and refresh the links. Do you need to create a chart, or could you not have a chart that refreshes with the data?